# Modifying database table during Entity Framework query

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

Let's say I have an Entity Framework context `context`, and execute the following:

```
foreach (var item in context.Set<MyObject>())
    DoSomethingThatTakesTenSeconds();
```

- Can I add new rows to `dbo.MyObject` in SSMS while this is executing? If so, are they picked up in the loop?
- Can I delete rows in `dbo.MyObject` in SSMS while this is executing? Will the loop still try to obtain them?
- What level of the EF/ADO.NET stack determines the answer to this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you access the first item in `IQueryable<T>`, the query is executed against database and results are materialized into collection of objects. Any modification of database will not change that collection. Answers to your questions:

1) You can add new objects, they are not picked up.

2) You can delete objects, they will be in loop.

3) It is how `IQueryable<T>` works, not EF/ADO.NET in particular.